# How to distribute the 'key' elements of a specific 'key' in JSON file across other dictionaries - Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
td1 ={}
td2 = {}
td3 = {}
td4 = {}
```

**test.json**

```
{
"a1":"a11",
"b1":"b11",
"c1":"c11",
"sub1":
    {
      "d1":"d11",
      "e1":"e11",
      "f1":"f11",
      ......
      ......
      ......
      "f10":"f100"
    },
"sub2":
    {
      "g1":"g11",
      "h1":"h11",
      "i1":"i11",
      ......
      ......
      ......
      "j10":"j100"
    }
}
```

Output should be :

```
td1 = {"d1":"sub1","g1":"sub2","f20":"sub1"}
td2 = {"e1":"sub1","h1":"sub2","d20":"sub1"}
td3 = {"e10":"sub1","h12":"sub2","d15":"sub1"}
td4 = {"f10":"sub1","j10":"sub2","f12":"sub1"}
```

All the elements of `JSON` content for `sub1` & `sub2`, should be equally distributed across 4 dictionaries (`td1,td2,td3,td4`)
Say, if sub1 has 12 elements then each of dictionaries will get 3 elements distributed. 
If 2, 3, 5, 13 or 14 number of elements present, it should be distributed accordingly.
Similar with `sub2` as well.

`No duplication`. If `d1` is already allotted to `td1,` it can't be allotted to any other dictionaries.

How can this be achieved ? `By grouping` ? or any other mechanism like `round-robin` or `unique` element concept ?

Comment: i do not get this : If 2, 3, 5, 13 or 14 number of elements present, it should be distributed accordingly

Comment: @Backtrack I mean, if the numbers can't be equally distributed.

Comment: If it has these many number of elements 2, 3, 5, 13 or 14 in sub1 or sub2, then it can't distributed equally. So, it should be distributed accordingly (elements may not be distributed equally).